# Wireshark Data as ASCII

Tags: lua, wireshark-dissector

I am polling a remote oscilloscope and the answer is "almost" pure ASCII:

[image: image_packet]

"Almost" because the 4-byte header `80 00 00 15` (`15` is the length of the ASCII message, in this case 21 bytes) doesn't let me decode the payload as ASCII in the column Data (neither when set as `Custom/data.data` nor `Custom/data.text`):

[image: image_column_appearance]

`Edit > Preferences > Protocols > Data`  has been already set as `Show data as text`

I would like to read the ASCII text as in `Follow TCP Stream`, where it is decoded correctly and the invalid ASCII codes changed to `.`:

[image]

Is there a way to remove the first 4 bytes without writing a dissector? 
I have no knowledge of Lua and no idea about how to write the dissector anyway: [10.3. Example: Dissector written in Lua](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsdg_html_chunked/wslua_dissector_example.html)  is well above my understanding.
Any pointer to a published solution that I can easily adapt is welcome.

Thank you

Comment: What is the format and meaning of those first 4 bytes?  It can't be a straight length value; otherwise the first byte, the 0x80 would alter the length.  Maybe you could supply a small capture file somewhere (Dropbox, Drive, ...)?

Comment: You could maybe take a look at the [guide](https://mika-s.github.io/wireshark/lua/dissector/2017/11/04/creating-a-wireshark-dissector-in-lua-1.html) I wrote on how to create Lua dissectors for Wireshark. I also found the official documentation a bit hard to understand, which is why I wrote the guide. I don't know whether there is an easier way or not to do it.

Comment: @ChristopherMaynard, `80 00 00 XX` is the beginning of payload. I never found a message longer than 54 bytes. I am reverse engineering the communication and only assume `80 00 00` is fixed. It could be a status of any kind, but I am interested only in the ASCII string.

Comment: @MikaS, great guide, thank you.

Comment: @AlexPoca, the length field could be a single byte field but it might also be a multi-byte field, 2, 3 or even 4 bytes with the exception of the most-significant bit of the 1st byte.  It's fine to assume it's a single byte, but you might want to just keep in mind that it could be a multi-byte field.  Maybe there's more information available about the message format from the manufacturer?  If not from their published documents then maybe through a support request?

Comment: @ChristopherMaynard, of course it could be longer, but I only need to configure the device: possibly longer messages are used when reading back stored data. I checked extensively more than 2500 parameter requests made by the producer's config program (that's, alas, not extensible and quite unpractical). It is for an internal project anyway. The documentation is quite miserable and we couldn't always save our config. Producer's software reads a param and writes it back soon with the same value: quite unusual, it looks like there are undescribed tricks here...
Thank you for your cooncerns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following [**MikaS tutorial**](https://mika-s.github.io/wireshark/lua/dissector/2017/11/04/creating-a-wireshark-dissector-in-lua-1.html) (very easy and well made!) I wrote this LUA dissector:

```lua
    yokogawa_protocol = Proto("YokogawaWT3000",  "Yokogawa WT3000 Protocol")

    message_header0 = ProtoField.int32("yokogawa_protocol.message_header0", "messageHeader0", base.DEC)
    message_header1 = ProtoField.int32("yokogawa_protocol.message_header1", "messageHeader1", base.DEC)
    message_header2 = ProtoField.int32("yokogawa_protocol.message_header2", "messageHeader2", base.DEC)
    message_length = ProtoField.int32("yokogawa_protocol.message_length", "messageLength", base.DEC)
    message_ascii  = ProtoField.string("yokogawa_protocol.message_ascii", "messageAscii", base.ASCII)

    yokogawa_protocol.fields = { message_header0, message_header1, message_header2, message_length, message_ascii }

    function yokogawa_protocol.dissector(buffer, pinfo, tree)
      length = buffer:len()
      if length == 0 then return end

      pinfo.cols.protocol = yokogawa_protocol.name

      local subtree = tree:add(yokogawa_protocol, buffer(), "Yokogawa WT3000 Protocol Data")

      subtree:add(message_header0, buffer(0,1)) -- fixed h80
      subtree:add(message_header1, buffer(1,1)) -- fixed h00
      subtree:add(message_header2, buffer(2,1)) -- fixed h00
      subtree:add(message_length, buffer(3,1))  -- ascii length
      subtree:add(message_ascii, buffer(4, length-4)) -- ascii text
    end

    local tcp_port = DissectorTable.get("tcp.port")
    tcp_port:add(10001, yokogawa_protocol)
```

Right-click on `messageAscii`, then `"Apply as Column"`, let me see the decoded value for each message in a new column.

Thanks everybody